# Communication in an entity-component through public variables or public member functions

Tags: entity-system, component-based, entity-component

I am currently coding my own ECS to get a deeper understanding of how such an engine works. I am currently putting together systems. I am aware that there is no right answer to my question as there are a lot of flavors of ECS. Probably I should say that I try to avoid an event queue at the moment. So I only want to do synchronous and direct communication.

Please note that this is the basis and preparation for my systems and event system for asynchronous communication.

How do you guys concept your components? Are you offering public variables directly accessed by the systems or do you communicate through public member functions?

**Public variable**

```
class AIComponent : public IComponent{
  public:
    bool m_LeftPressed = bool();
}
```

**Public member function**

```
class AIComponent : public IComponent{
  private:
    bool m_LeftPressed = bool();

  public:
    bool leftPressed();
}
```

Comment: Aren't they the exact same? Or perhaps I misunderstand what you mean. Could you give one example of both concepts?

Comment: Sure. I added examples

Comment: There are so many forms of ECS around that there is no way anyone can definitively answer this, and it would only lead to discussion which we discourage here. What I will say is this: public data members are the easy way to start; I personally make all members in my data model, public. Public getters can be more useful when you are trying to debug "who accessed this variable last", since you can put trace/log statements in them.

Comment: Yes. I agree and I am aware that this is provably a opinion (flavor) driven discussion. But your statement already gives me some insights. So your components are only containing data and you do all the logic in the systems?

Comment: What about using directly structs?

Comment: That would be the consequence if I decide to go for data-only components. Do you guys have no logic in your components? I tend to go into this direction when reading the comments. Are there consequences, e.g. for systems, inter-entity communication etc.?